# Custom sty files not being detected in vscode using latex-workshop extension

Tags: pdftex, latex3, latex-workshop

I am trying to compile and generate pdf for my thesis project in latex.
Below is the project structure:

```
|-tex
|--thesis
|---packages
|----color.sty
|---common
|----lang.sty
|---thesis.tex
|---thesis.cls
```

I am using the .sty files in the thesis.cls file but I am getting the "...sty File not found" error.
Doing some research, I tried the setting the following env variable:
`export TEXINPUTS=.:./tex/thesis/common/:./tex/thesis/packages/`
But still the same error. What am I missing here.
(I am using OSX, hence the `:` separator)

Error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `lang.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
./thesis.cls:68: Emergency stop.
<read *>
```

`thesis.cls` class code which is invoking the sty files and failing here:

```
\LoadClassWithOptions{report}
\RequirePackage{lang}.  <--- Fails here
\RequirePackage{color}
.....
```

Comment: As far as I know, macOS (hasn't been called OSX in years) doesn't use `:` as folder delimitor. That was in use thirty years ago, until OS9, but after that it started using Unix convention.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It doesn't work even if I use a single path.

Comment: If you want more help, you should provide useful information, like a minimal but compilable code and the detail of the error messages.

Comment: I have updated the question with error msg and some code. Thanks

Comment: There should be no need for a local color.sty. That should be in every tex system if latex is installed.

Comment: You are compiling this from inside the ``tex`` directory, right? Then your ``TEXINPUTS`` search paths are looking inside directories ``./tex/tex/thesis/{common,packages}/`` for the file ``lang.sty``, which is not available (notice the duplication of ``tex/tex``).
I suggest, you add all subdirectories into the search path, e.g. ``TEXINPUTS=.//`` to search all child directories recursively.

Comment: I am compiling inside the thesis folder and tried setting this in the terminal :
`export TEXINPUTS=.:./common/:./packages/` but still didn't work 
Do i need to set it in the settings.json or somewhere else that the latex workshop extension needs to understand ?